# "would be expected to be happening"

Tags: grammar

Is this phrase sound?

> Performance of modern filesystems is getting close to physical
>   limitations of underlying hard-drives. Processing of big files **would
>   be expected to be happening** at high throughput close to underlying
>   device performance. Processing of small files **would be expected to
>   be happening** at high rate due to write-back caches.

Answer (score 2):

'would be expected to happen at a high rate' or 'would be expected to occur at a high rate'

Comment: Can `occur` mean a continuous process or only a single event?