# Does the phrase "expected to occur" express a continuous event?

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests, word-usage

Can the phrase '*expected to occur*' mean a continuous event? My understanding is that it would rather mean a single, one-time or repeatable event that is likely or assumed to happen in the near future.

Please clarify on the matter.

For reference, this particular phrase was used in ["would be expected to be happening"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/285845/would-be-expected-to-be-happening).

Answer (score 1):

"Expected to occur" is a one-time event (at least according to the topic you referred to).
Though this isn't always true (there are other factors involved such as additional word usage, etc.).

For example, *We expected the attack to occur at night, but we were wrong.*

Answer (score 1):

The usage of 'expected to occur' can be both singular and plural depending on the context.  Similar to the usage of 'you' as both singular and plural.

As a project manager, I would use 'occur' in its plural form to describe an event that was likely to happen repeatedly, and 'occurrence' or 'when X occurs' to describe a more singular circumstance.

Comment: Catch: Here `occur` refers to a continuous, not repeatable, event.